# SQL While Loop exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a list of dates from one cell in SQL. These dates are all in one cell in SQL `"....d|43460)())(0||1(d|42534)())(0||2(d|40910)())(0||3(d|41855)..."`
I've managed to write a query that gets the first date

```
SELECT Substring (clndr_data , CHARINDEX('d|', clndr_data)+2, 5)
FROM [x].[dbo].[CALENDAR]
where clndr_id = '954'
```

I need to get all other dates, so I assume that I have to use While or Loop to get all dates after 'd|'? Will be grateful if someone can help.

Required Output (This should be a list but i can't show it here):

```
Number Date
43460 26/12/2018
42534 13/06/2016
40910 02/01/2012
```

Comment: where did the `Date` column comes from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @clndr_data varchar(MAX)    =   'd|43460)())(0||1(d|42534)())(0||2(d|40910)())(0||3(d|41855)'
DECLARE @walker     int             =   0
DECLARE @holder     varchar(MAX)    =   @clndr_data
DECLARE @date       varchar(5)
DECLARE @tempTb     table([value] varchar(50))

WHILE CHARINDEX('d|', @holder) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @walker = CHARINDEX('d|', @holder) + 2
    SET @date = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@holder, @walker, 5))
    INSERT INTO @tempTb VALUES (@date)
    SET @holder = SUBSTRING(@holder, @walker + 5, LEN(@holder))
END

SELECT * FROM @tempTb
```

Just replace `@clndr_data` with your actual `clndr_data` column. Don't forget to set `@holder` variable to the value of this column.

`SET @holder = (SELECT clndr_data FROM [x].[dbo].[CALENDAR] WHERE clndr_id = '954')`

```
DECLARE @walker     int             =   0
DECLARE @holder     varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @date       varchar(5)
DECLARE @tempTb     table([value] varchar(50))

SET @holder = (SELECT clndr_data FROM [x].[dbo].[CALENDAR] WHERE clndr_id = '954')

WHILE CHARINDEX('d|', @holder) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @walker = CHARINDEX('d|', @holder) + 2
    SET @date = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@holder, @walker, 5))
    INSERT INTO @tempTb VALUES (@date)
    SET @holder = SUBSTRING(@holder, @walker + 5, LEN(@holder))
END

SELECT * FROM @tempTb
```

Comment: Thank you very much @CurseStacker, I'm very new to this and this is not my background so forgive my ignorance. Where exactly should I add the last statement (SET holder = (Select clndr_data From ....where clndr_id = '954')) in the query that you wrote? Also do you mean the top line should be Declare clndr_data varchar(MAX) = clndr_data? Again Many Thanks :)

Comment: You need to change `DECLARE @date varchar(5) ` to `DECLARE @date date`. Then change `SET @date..` line to `SET @date = DATEADD(D, CAST((SELECT SUBSTRING(@holder, @walker, 5)) AS int) - 2, '01/01/1900')`.

Comment: Caveat: I'm not very sure why pasting the values `43460`, `42534`, etc. to excel converts it to how many days it is after `01/01/1990` minus 2, but I just followed it and put a `- 2` as well in this query.

Comment: Your best bet is to consult the people who encode these dates to verify which date they encoded, the one with - 2 or what.

Comment: Again your query worked! this is exactly what I was looking for, you have no idea how much this has helped me. One last thing, if I may, apologies for all the additional questions, Is it possible in the final output to add a column next to the dates, showing the "clndr_id"?? as I will use this to link to another table in the database.

Comment: Just add another variable `DECLARE @clndr_id int`
Then set the value same way as you get the value of `clndr_data`.
`SET @clndr_id = (SELECT clndr_id FROM ..`
Then add another column in your `@tempTB`.
`DECLARE @tempTb  table([id] int, [value] varchar(50))`
Then insert the ID.
`INSERT INTO @tempTb VALUES (@clndr_id, @date)`

Comment: Hi @CurseStacker, sorry I need to edit the query to get all dates that are only between '|d' and ')()'.....so for example (0||3(d|41429)())      (0||4(d|41464)(        (0||0(s|09:00|f|15:00)()))) returns only 41429. Do you think this is doable?

Comment: Table "Task" has many clndr_id is it possible to change the query from SET clndr_id = (SELECT clndr_id FROM [PMDB].[dbo].[TASK]where proj_id = '4610') to for example SET clndr_id IN (SELECT clndr_id FROM [PMDB].[dbo].[TASK]where proj_id = '4610')....sorry I'm asking you a lot of question but I feel you understand what I'm trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

you can treat `clndr_data` as a delimited string and make use of delimited string splitter to split it into multiple item in a list. Here i am using `")("` as delimiter

Here i am using `DelimitedSplit8K()` by Jeff Moden from http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Note : you will need to create the function first

```
SELECT  clndr_data, right(Item, 5) as Number
FROM    [x].[dbo].[CALENDAR]
        CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(clndr_data, ')(')
where   clndr_id = '954'
and     Item    like '%d|%'
```