# SQL Insert Data to Temporary Table and Save the result as a View

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do two things with the below query:

1. edit the query to get all dates that are only between `'d|'` and `')()'`.....so for example in clndr_data `(0||3(d|41429)()) (0||4(d|41464)( (0||0(s|09:00|f|15:00)())))` returns only `41429`. The query below returns all dates after  `'|d'`.
2. Store the output as View (Proj_ID, Clndr_ID, Dates)

```
DECLARE @project_name   varchar(50) =   'NA63-TEN-20-05-12-01'
DECLARE @project_id     int         =   (SELECT [proj_id] FROM [PMDB].[dbo].   [PROJECT] WHERE [proj_short_name] = @project_name)
DECLARE @calendar       int         =   (SELECT [clndr_id] FROM [PMDB].[dbo].[PROJECT] WHERE [proj_short_name] = @project_name)
DECLARE @clndr_id       int
DECLARE @walker         int         =   0
DECLARE @holder         varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @date           date
DECLARE @temp_tb        table([id] int , [value] varchar(50))

SET @holder = (SELECT [clndr_data] FROM [PMDB].[dbo].[CALENDAR] WHERE [clndr_id] = @calendar )
SET @clndr_id = (SELECT [clndr_id] FROM [PMDB].[dbo].[CALENDAR] WHERE [clndr_id] = @calendar)

WHILE CHARINDEX('d|', @holder) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @walker = CHARINDEX('d|', @holder) + 2
    SET @date = DATEADD(D, CAST((SELECT SUBSTRING(@holder, @walker, 5)) AS int) - 2, '01/01/1900')
    INSERT INTO @temp_tb VALUES (@clndr_id, @date)
    SET @holder = SUBSTRING(@holder, @walker + 5, LEN(@holder))
END

SELECT * FROM @temp_tb
```

Comment: why not used the solution that i have posted in your earlier question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52213896/sql-while-loop-exists It is not loop based so you can create it as a view

Comment: The text mentions `|d` mulitple times, while the code uses `d|`. Please be exact and precise.

Comment: @Squirrel, Thanks mate I tried your code but it doesn't work, I'm sure you are expecting me to add something, but this is not my background so I just want the complete code, many thanks though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I joined your `PROJECT` and `CALENDAR` tables. Then set the parameters to the corresponding values of `proj_id` and `clndr_id` for preparation before `INSERT` since the value for the `date_value` column needs to be processed first inside the `WHILE`.

> Connected to the question : [SQL While Loop exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52213896/sql-while-loop-exists)

```
DECLARE @project_name   varchar(50)     = 'NA63-TEN-20-05-12-01'
DECLARE @project_id     int
DECLARE @clndr_id       int
DECLARE @walker         int             =   0
DECLARE @holder         varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @date           date
DECLARE @data           varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @temp_tb        table([proj_id] int, [clndr_id] int , [date_value] date)

SELECT @project_id = [p].[proj_id]
      ,@clndr_id = [p].[clndr_id]
      ,@holder = [c].[clndr_data]
FROM [PMDB].[dbo].[PROJECT] AS [p]
INNER JOIN [PMDB].[dbo].[CALENDAR] AS [c] ON [p].[clndr_id] = [c].[clndr_id]
WHERE [p].[proj_short_name] = @project_name


WHILE @walker <> LEN(@holder) + 1
BEGIN
    IF SUBSTRING(@holder, @walker, 2) = 'd|'
    BEGIN
        SET @data = SUBSTRING(@holder, @walker, 10)
        IF SUBSTRING(@data, LEN(@data) - 2, 3) = ')()'
        BEGIN
            SET @date = DATEADD(D, CAST(SUBSTRING(@data, 3, 5) AS int) -2, '01/01/1900')
            INSERT INTO @return_tb VALUES (@project_id, @clndr_id, @date)
        END
    END
    SET @walker = @walker + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @temp_tb
```

If you want to save this as a `view`, create the code above as `function` first.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      
-- Create date: 
-- Description: 
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION GetProjectDates 
(   
     @project_name  varchar(50)
)
RETURNS @return_tb TABLE([proj_id] int, [clndr_id] int , [date_value] date)
AS
BEGIN 
    -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
    DECLARE @project_id int
    DECLARE @clndr_id   int
    DECLARE @walker     int             =   0
    DECLARE @holder     varchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @date       date
    DECLARE @data       varchar(MAX)

    SELECT @project_id = [p].[proj_id]
          ,@clndr_id = [p].[clndr_id]
          ,@holder = [c].[clndr_data]
    FROM [PMDB].[dbo].[PROJECT] AS [p]
    INNER JOIN [PMDB].[dbo].[CALENDAR] AS [c] ON [p].[clndr_id] = [c].[clndr_id]
    WHERE [p].[proj_short_name] = @project_name

    WHILE @walker <> LEN(@holder) + 1
    BEGIN
        IF SUBSTRING(@holder, @walker, 2) = 'd|'
        BEGIN
            SET @data = SUBSTRING(@holder, @walker, 10)
            IF SUBSTRING(@data, LEN(@data) - 2, 3) = ')()'
            BEGIN
                SET @date = DATEADD(D, CAST(SUBSTRING(@data, 3, 5) AS int) -2, '01/01/1900')
                INSERT INTO @return_tb VALUES (@project_id, @clndr_id, @date)
            END
        END
        SET @walker = @walker + 1
    END

    RETURN
END
GO
```

Then save the code below as your view:

```
SELECT * FROM [GetProjectDates]('NA63-TEN-20-05-12-01')
```

Comment: thanks for the usual support, but I was also trying to get the dates that are only between 'd|' and ')()'. This code gets all dates. Do you think this can be done? Again I appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: Is it always in the first part of the `date_value`?

Comment: Thanks @CurseStacker for the reply, I'm not sure exactly what you mean,
 your query gets every date after 'd|' in the clndr_data, I need the same final output but only dates between 'd|' and ')()'.....This is an sample of the data in clndr_data (However they are much more than that, but just to show you an example).....(0||3(d|41429)()) (0||4(d|41464)( (0||0(s|09:00|f|15:00)()))).....I don't want to get the date for the second one because it's not between 'd|' and ')()'.....this is random in the clndr_data (i.e. there is no pattern)...I hope I clarified a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but might be below query will help you. As I assumed like date value in 5 digit only.

```
create table #yourtable (
    cola varchar(1000)
    )
;

insert into #yourtable
values ('(0||3(d|41429)())')

insert into #yourtable
values ('(0||4(d|41464)( (0||0(s|09:00|f|15:00)())))')

select  SUBSTRING(cola,9,5)
from #yourtable
where PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])()%', cola )>0
```